# jQueryMobile don't bind clicks on next page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The only way to bind event on next page is to put it directly inside onclick="...", which is not an option. Nothing helps, can't bind click after page is loaded via JQM ajax.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('#link').on('click', function() {
      alert(); 
      return false;
    });
});

<div data-role="page" class="pages">
    <a id="link" href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use classes to address `data-role=page` elements. Always use ID's. Using classes sometimes gives out erratic behaviour.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <a id="link" href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

You could bind your `#link`'s `click` event inside the `pageinit` event of `page1`:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1' ,function() {
    $(this).on('click', '#link',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Clicked"); 
      return false;
    });
});
```

But, if you want to use a common `pageinit` for all pages (which isn't advisable), you could bind that click to the document :

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $(document).on('click', "#page1 #link" , function(e) { // or simply "#link"
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Clicked"); 
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `pageinit` fires only once/page. so the event will be attached only once. and you musnt use `ready` with jQM.